# os.system(ping) всегда возвращает 1

Tags: python, ос, ping

Есть небольшой код на проверку доступности ір адреса

```
import os

ip = "8.8.8.8"
status = os.system("ping {}".format(ip))
if status == 0:
   print("Ok")
else:
   print:("bad try")
```

Но она все время возвращает 1. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У меня возвращает ноль. А через консоль если пинговать, пинг проходит?

Comment: @Alpensin Да, если через консоль, то все замечательно

Comment: Какая у вас операционка? В документации сказано, что в POSIX системах возвращаемое значение может быть разным, в зависимости от системы, и там рекомендуют использовать модуль `subprocess` вместо `os`

Comment: @iksuy Про это не знал, я только изучаю язык, поэтому не знаком с этими нюансами. Вызов остается таким же?

Comment: @iksy только что использовал в такой конструкции: 
`import subprocess as sp
   ip = "172.217.20.206"
   status = sp.getstatusoutput ("ping {}".format(ip))
   if status == 0:
      print("Ok")
   else:
      print:("not ping")`

Результат тот же

Comment: `getstatusoutput` возвращает `Tuple` вида `(status, output)`, например:
`(0, 'PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=16.2 ms)`, т.е. вам нужно `status[0]` смотреть.

Comment: @iksuy Все равно на выходе 1 при любых исходах

Comment: Какая ОС всё-таки? Здесь поведение зависит не от питона, а от конкретной версии утилиты ping в конкретной версии ОС.

Comment: Кроме того, в POSIX-системах обычно пинг по умолчанию бесконечный, и в прописанной здесь команде не видно какого-либо ограничения на число пакетов. Как и кем останавливается пинг? Возможно, именно неаккуратный процесс остановки и приводит к возникновению кода 1 (но это опять же зависит от версии утилиты и ОС)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение проблемы

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

DNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
ip_request = "192.168.0.1"
status = subprocess.call(["ping","-n","1",ip_request],stdout = DNULL)
if status == 0:
   print ("It`s up!")
else:
    print ("It`s down!")
```

Для Linux вместо "-n" использовать "-c"

Comment: Вы импортируете `multiprocessing`, но не используете его.